# Use Expression Function as Inline Call

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

As an example, I have the following expression:

```cs
private static Expression<Func<User, UserResponse>> MapToResponse = k => new UserResponse()
{
    Id = k.Id,
};
```

Usage in EF/Linq:

```cs
UserResponse response = db.Users.Select(MapToResponse).FirstOrDefault(k=> k.Id == id);
```

I am trying to reuse as following:

```cs
User user = new();

await db.Users.AddAsync(user);

await db.SaveChangesAsync();

// the idea
UserResponse response = MapToResponse(user);
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does it work if you compile the expression? Are you building the expressions dynamically in reality? Otherwise, why not just declare a `Func<User, UserResponse>` instead of an `Expression<Func<User, UserResponse>>`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks! wasn't aware of that. I'll try:   `var fn = MapToResponse.Compile();` then `fn(user)`

Comment: Why dont you use AutoMapper?

Comment: Note that using `Compile` is very slow and should be skipped if possible. Just declare `MapToResponse` as `Func<>`.